# Deleting lines starting with * in a text file using sed or awk?

Tags: bash

I had text file, I'd like to **delete the line** with starts with *

I tried using grep, it doesn't workout.

```
grep -v '^#'
```

Suggestions appreciated.

```
\n
OG0018658
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M1~439516e2a637051372399975c71af47b | 0.009414**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M5~d51f0107310c1d9a8cbe5b0305c46986 | 0.009341**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M6~462cfd85f3d26c451e0ea388b1ee265e | 0.009341**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M7~f3c7a863e871762d7674e5a6f6aa1b0d | 0.009438**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |          M8a~17a2f94c77ce46d91db4dc8a50d30fd7 | 0.034070*
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.167
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.179
   * Sites significantly caracterized
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.179
   * Sites significantly caracterized
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.176
   * Sites significantly caracterized
   * Average omega for all tree: nan
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.175
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.175
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.174
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.174
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.177
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.167
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.179
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.179
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.176
   * Average omega for all tree: nan
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.175
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.175
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.174
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.174
   * Average omega for all tree: 0.177


Modified file


\n
OG0018658
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M1~439516e2a637051372399975c71af47b | 0.009414**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M5~d51f0107310c1d9a8cbe5b0305c46986 | 0.009341**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M6~462cfd85f3d26c451e0ea388b1ee265e | 0.009341**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |           M7~f3c7a863e871762d7674e5a6f6aa1b0d | 0.009438**
                M0~bbe9a2ca8a9915aafa220a87c248a064 |          M8a~17a2f94c77ce46d91db4dc8a50d30fd7 | 0.034070*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple awk solution:

```
awk '$1!="*"' infile
```

The equivalent sed solution:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*\*/d' infile
```

And the same regex used in grep:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*\*' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

But they actually start with some whitespace characters.

`grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*\*' file.txt`

Comment: How do I remove the white spaces ?